# REST post request with optional file upload

Tags: c#, wcf

while creating WCF REST service, i am receiving data in json and able to save in database. now i need to give option to upload file(optional, image or video) with same service. i tried sending byte array but it is giving bad request error possibly because of serialization of such a long array. i read that to upload large files i need to use stream. how would i do that while sending other parameters? i am creating this service to receive data from mobile device. here is my service interface

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "SaveFBPost", 
    Method = "POST", 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
void SaveFacebookPost(FBPostData fbPostData);
```

public class FBPostData:

```
[DataMember]
public string scheduleDate { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string userId { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string groupId { get; set; } 

[DataMember]
public string postText { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public byte[] file { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string fileType { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public string accessToken { get; set; }
```

Comment: if any one has any doubt that i am not putting effort then you can see its been a whole day and i am still on same problem. and i searched for 1 more day before posting here. may be a little guidance in right direction. anyone?

Comment: You need to post some more substantial code samples - did you adjust maxBuffferSize and maxArrayLength?

Comment: yes i increased the maxBuffferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize. there was lot of confusing and conflicting(at least for beginner like me) info on net. like in a blog you mentioned says "WCF will not let you have any other parameters if using streams". well it does. you can also pass parameters to Webinvoke and you can certainly send stream using REST. i am using multipart file uploading now. seem to be working but not fully tested. will update here

Comment: and apologies for late responses. i am also working on android side and there was a weekend in between :)

Comment: i have given the solution of this problem. thanks a lot of help and followup

Comment: if there was information that was helpful, please upvote those users.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by increasing maxBufferSize and maxArrayLength for the particular binding in the web.config, and see if that resolves the issue.

You should be able to pull up some more specifics on the error as well, so you can see exactly why you are getting your 400 error.

[This blog article](http://garfoot.com/blog/2008/06/transferring-large-files-using-wcf/) was also useful for me in the past - there are some good links at the bottom as well.

Also take look at the [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) class. Not sure what you mean by "sending other parameters" - If you can clarify this, we can give you some more direction on that.

Comment: i am looking at the blog you mentioned and will get back to you. as for other parameters, like i said, i was sending other data with this api call as you can see in FBPostData class. this only works if i remove the file byte array for file uploading.

Comment: it was very helpful article but still no luck. i was using webinvoke but now i am using SOAP instaed as steam cannot be done with REST? now my service is not getting hit at all. may be i messed up my configuration. can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

i had to use stream using multipart upload from android and multipart parser to solve this issue. i used Apache mime library to upload file and send parameters like this:

```
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                context.getString(R.string.url_service_fbpost));
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        if(postData.data != null && !"".equals(postData.fileName)){
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(postData.data, postData.fileName);
            reqEntity.addPart("uploaded", bab);
        }
        reqEntity.addPart("scheduleDate", new StringBody(postData.scheduleDate));
        reqEntity.addPart("userId", new StringBody(postData.userId));
        reqEntity.addPart("groupIds",
                new StringBody(postData.groupIds.toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("postText", new StringBody(postData.postText));
        reqEntity.addPart("postType", new StringBody(postData.postType));
        reqEntity.addPart("accessToken", new StringBody(postData.accessToken));
        if(postData.postId != null && postData.postId.length() > 0) {
            reqEntity.addPart("postId", new StringBody(postData.postId));
        }
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

after that i used c# multipart parser to get file and parameters. here is the code for service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "UploadFBPost",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
void UploadFBPost(Stream stream);

 public void UploadFBPost(Stream stream)
{
    MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(stream);

    // Saves post data in database
    if (parser.Success)
    {
        string fileName = null, userId = null, postText = null, postType = null, accessToken = null;
        DateTime scheduleDate = DateTime.Now;
        string[] groupIds = null;
        int postId = 0;

        // Other contents
        foreach (MyContent content in parser.MyContents)
        {
            switch (content.PropertyName)
            {
                case "scheduleDate":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content.StringData.Trim()))
                        scheduleDate = DateTime.Now;
                    else
                        scheduleDate = DateTime.ParseExact(content.StringData.Trim(), "M-d-yyyy H:m:s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    break;

                case "fileName":
                    fileName = content.StringData.Trim();
                    break;

                case "userId":
                    userId = content.StringData.Trim();
                    break;

                case "postText":
                    postText = content.StringData.Trim();
                    break;

                case "accessToken":
                    accessToken = content.StringData.Trim();
                    break;

                case "groupIds":
                    groupIds = content.StringData.Trim().Split(new char[] { ',' });
                    break;

                case "postType":
                    postType = content.StringData.Trim();
                    break;

                case "postId":
                    postId = Convert.ToInt32(content.StringData.Trim());
                    break;
            }
        }

        string videoFile = null, imageFile = null;
        if (parser.FileContents != null)
        {
            string filePath = GetUniqueUploadFileName(parser.Filename);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, parser.FileContents);
            if (postType == "photo")
                imageFile = Path.GetFileName(filePath); 
            else 
                videoFile = Path.GetFileName(filePath); 
        }
    }
}
```

you do need to modify multipart parser according to data you are sending. hope this will save time of few.

thanks ray for the help.

one more thing. i had to add these lines in web config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000"/>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferSize="65536"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"
             transferMode="Streamed">
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```